# Creating a constraint in Oracle that depends on other columns

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

Please consider the following table structure on Oracle:

```
create table DOCS
(
  DOC_NO   NUMBER not null,
  DOC_TYPE VARCHAR2(5) not null,
  PMT_NO   NUMBER not null
);
```

In this table, the PMT_NO column has to be unique except when DOC_NO is the same and DOC_TYPE is different:

```
    DOC_NO DOC_TYPE     PMT_NO
---------- -------- ----------
         1 A                10 <-- good
         1 B                10 <-- good, DOC_NO is the same
         2 C                10 <-- NOT good, DOC_NO is different
```

PMT_NO cannot repeat and cannot have "holes" (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 5), so a sequence would not work. And there are many users inserting data at the same time.

Is there a way to create a unique key / unique index / function-based index for that condition?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, not allowing "holes" is just asking for a failure in the future. There's not any good reason *not* to allow holes, and then sequences will work wonderfully for generating your next PMT_NO. Even so, you aren't normalized as @Randy suggests; split this into two tables with DOC_NO,DOC_TYPE and DOC_NO,PMT_NO and your problems go away.

Comment: Randy and Kerri, thank you both for your help!
Randy, I agree that this isn't normalized properly. However, this is an existing table which is used extensively throughout the system, and changing it now would be extremely expensive and dangerous.
Kerri, we really can't allow holes in this column, it's a basic business rule in our system.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, today we control that by looking for repeated values just before commit and updating them. But that doesn't work 100% of times and we need to force a table lock before that, which causes serious performance issues. That is why a constraint would be a much better option.

Comment: @ricsmania even if you persist this non-normalized table, you could still create another properly normalized link table, and use a trigger to insert to hat one when this one is updated.. then the constraint would be checked, and the bad records prevented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a normalization problem.

You could pull out the relevant tuple into another table such that the row would be unique.

In this case link `doc_no` to `pmt_no`, once (not repeated as you have shown).

Then you can make a unique index on the `pmt_no` column of this link table.

Comment: I used your idea and created a trigger to populate another table, as you suggested on your comment, and it work perfectly. Thank you very much!